# Why where 2 of my questions deleted?

Tags: support, moderation, deleted-questions

Why were my question deleted by the **community**?

[fail2ban broken after dist upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136673/fail2ban-broken-after-dist-upgrade)
https://askubuntu.com/questions/113721/how-can-i-disable-the-php-gettext-module

I want go get a solution for that problems. Dammed I didn't fixed that for almost a year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update/improve your questions occasionally with your progress in order to avoid deletion:

- [Enable automatic deletion of old, unanswered zero-score questions after a year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006)

Neither one of your questions has been touched in a year!

Comment: Okay that is a reason, however I don't know how I should improve my question. A solution for my fail2ban problem would interest me just today too.

Comment: @rekire we mean adding in details like a list of things you've tried, a list of resources you've already tried, etc.  Generally just adding information as you try things and such.  Otherwise, untouched, zero-score stuff will get purged.

Comment: @TheLord I just found out something out. Maybe I find out something more...